# maven error: The desired archetype does not exist (org.phpmaven:php5-web-archetype:2.0-SNAPSHOT)

Tags: maven

I am trying to create php project using maven by tying below command:

```
sudo mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.phpmaven 
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-web-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT 
  -DgroupId=org.sample -DartifactId=my-app -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

but it gives me error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) 
  on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.phpmaven:php5-web-archetype:2.0-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: from where you got that command? have you followed the preparation steps? which steps did you do, prior to this?

Comment: i got this command from http://www.php-maven.org/branches/2.0-SNAPSHOT/php-web-5min.html and i also followed preparation steps( like creating settings.xml in .m2/repository/. but still it gives me same error. where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you're trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.php-maven.org/branches/2.0-SNAPSHOT/php-lib-10min.html). If you do, you should also do the [preparation steps](http://www.php-maven.org/prepare.html) that have been listed.

Doing that you're relying on a snapshot archetype, and those do not exist in default repositories, so you have to configure php-maven snapshot repository.

After doing that,

1. Confirm your settings.xml location (in the comments you indicated you had that in the wrong folder)
2. try with

   `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.phpmaven.sites
     -DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-web-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0-beta-1 
     -DgroupId=org.sample -DartifactId=my-app -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Since you can see from [the repo](http://nexus.php-maven.org/content/groups/release-repo1.php-maven.org/archetype-catalog.xml) that that archetype version should be in place. Note the different archetypeversion and different archetypegroupid!

Comment: i have also done preparation steps as stated in http://www.php-maven.org/prepare.html. i have created settings.xml in m2/repository/

Comment: @user2282615 why you have created it in there? the instructions say it should be created in `~/.m2`, not in `m2/repository`.

Comment: sorry for mistake. now i have moved settings.xml from .m2/repository to .m2/settings.xml. and run again above command but still it gives me same error                       
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere. 
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/phpmaven/sites/php5-web-archetype/2.0.0-beta-1/php5-web-archetype-2.0.0-beta-1.jar

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: @user2282615 please add to your question the full output as well as the exact command you now use